# Disable the enitire string when live editing in Elementor

Tags: javabeans, elementor

I have used the beans framework in Wordpress. It uses the UIKIT.

I want page with only the beans navbar(transparent) with elementor on the rest of the page. I have achieved this. But when i enter the code in style.css Elementor stoppes responding i live edit. I think the Z-index messes up the editor

I have entered this code:

```
.tm-main{
    position:relative;
    top:-240px;
    z-index:-10;
}
```

It solves the problem and places elementor underneath the navbar. This makes my slideshow appear under menu items, as it should.

I want to be able to disable my string when im in the editor. No need for the navbar when edition.

Something like this:

```
.tm-main{
    position:relative;
    top:-240px;
    z-index:-10;
  DISABLE STRING WHEN .elementor-editor-active
}
```

Is this possible? thx!